# pandas.Series.append() adding new value as an extra column rather than appending it to the end of the series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

I'm writing a program that reads a Series of `comment.id`s from a CSV file, appends a new `comment.id` to the Series, and then saves the new Series as a CSV.

Here is what I have:

```
def get_cache(path_=PATH_CACHE):
    """"
    If cache does not exist, it creates one. Otherwise, it loads the 
    cache into memory.
    """
    print('Searching for cache...')
    if os.path.exists(path_)==True:
        print('Cache exists')
        cache = pd.read_csv(path_)
        print('Cache loaded')
    else:
        print('Cache does not exist')
        cache = pd.Series(['test1', 'test2'], name='commentid', dtype=str)
        print('Cache created')

    return cache

def run(reddit, reply, cache, sub='test'):
    """
    Posts on the specified subreddit if a comment containing a keyword 
    is found. Updates cache in memory.
    """
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(sub)
    comments = subreddit.comments(limit=25)

    print('Searching for comments...')

    for comment in comments:
        comment_text = comment.body
        isMatch = any(string in comment_text for string in MATCH_WORDS)
        if isMatch and comment.id not in cache.values:
            print('Comment found!')
            # comment.reply(reply)
            print('Replied!')
            cache = cache.append(pd.Series([comment.id], dtype=str),
                                 ignore_index=True)      

            print('{} added to cache'.format(comment.id))
        else:
            print('Skip')
          
    print('Done Searching \nCache:\n {}'.format(cache))

    return cache

def update_cache(cache, path_=PATH_CACHE):
    """
    Saves cache as csv to same path as it was loaded in from, replacing 
    the csv file.
    """
    cache.to_csv(path_, index=False)
    print('Cache saved as csv')
```

When a new `comment.id` is found, I get the following for `cache`:

[image]

where `gshiiiq` is the `comment.id` that was found when `run()` was called. I would instead like to get `gshiiiq` appended to the end of the existing column, with no new column added.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is `cache` a pd.Series that you are passing into the run() function?

Comment: maybe you should use a list instead of pd.Series; and convert it into pd.Series at the very end of program, i.e. do the conversion as late as possible.

Comment: the problem is likely because you are trying to append a `pd.Series` to a `pd.DataFrame`  - `pd.read_csv` doesn't return a Series with the default  options

Comment: @AsishM. Yes! Thank you. 

I didn't realize `pd.read_csv()` returns a dataframe. I set `squeeze=True` and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

As AsishM. pointed out in his comment, `pd.read_csv()` returns a dataframe by default. I set `squeeze=True` and it returns a Series.